# Extract Email ID from google form and create a folder on google drive based on the email id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to create a folder on Google Drive based on the response I get on the google form. 
I have asked user's to input their Email Address in the form. I want to use this Email Address to create a folder on Google Drive!

I have come up with the following code below ( not optimized ) to create the folder!

```
function myfunction() {
var form = FormApp.openById('1EDIT8BSfCUdKxgMLgIjP9VJGPJlQFMHZFpQqa6R_bMs');
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
var formResponse = formResponses[i];
var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
var email = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
DriveApp.createFolder(email)}};
}
```

I am able to create a New Folder after every response is recorded using the trigger function but for some reason the Folder created does not the Email Id entered by the user.

Here is the Executable Transcript -

```
[17-09-26 13:07:39:569 PDT] Starting execution
[17-09-26 13:07:39:655 PDT] 
FormApp.openById([1EDIT8BSfCUdKxgMLgIjP9VJGPJlQFMHZFpQqa6R_bMs]) [0.079 
seconds]
[17-09-26 13:07:40:495 PDT] Form.getResponses() [0.839 seconds]
[17-09-26 13:07:40:496 PDT] FormResponse.getItemResponses() [0 seconds]
[17-09-26 13:07:40:496 PDT] ItemResponse.getResponse() [0 seconds]
[17-09-26 13:07:41:315 PDT] 
DriveApp.createFolder([0B5FjIzaVY166ZVdjc251T2VnUjA]) [0.818 seconds]
[17-09-26 13:07:41:317 PDT] Execution succeeded [1.74 seconds total runtime]
```

As you can notice the Driveapp.Createfolder takes on some unknown value! 
How do I fix this?

Comment: I guess your referring to this `DriveApp.createFolder([0B5FjIzaVY166ZVdjc251T2VnUjA])`.  My guess is that's the id of the new folder.  So what do you want to fix?

Comment: It's good that you looked at the Execution Transcript, but you need to know what the value of `email` is, and you can use `Logger.log('email: ' + email)` to print something to the logs.  `var email = itemResponses[0].getResponse(); Logger.log('email: ' + email)`  Run the code and then View the Logs.  What is the value of `email` ?

Comment: @Cooper That might be the ID, I am not quite sure! But I want to create a folder in google drive with the text entered by user in the E-Mail field that exists in the form! Folders are getting created every time a user fills in that form but I want the name of folder to be the user's Email Address and not the ID of the folder! For example if a user enters - "Cooper@Gmail.com" I want to create a folder in my drive named Cooper@Gmail.com

Comment: @SandyGood I am getting this value even after entering a valid Email ID in the form -
   [17-09-27 02:50:25:694 PDT] email: 0B5FjIzaVY166ZVdjc251T2VnUjA

I entered test@gmail.com in the form and ended up getting a folder named '0B5FjIzaVY166ZVdjc251T2VnUjA' in my Drive. I want a folder that is named test@gmail.com

Comment: Your code is always getting the first response in the Form.  It doesn't matter how many Form submissions that you make, your code is never getting anything other than the first response.  Your first `for` loop never goes above zero, and your second `for` loop also never goes above zero.  The code is always getting the first response and the first question / answer.  So, it doesn't matter how you answer the question in the Form.

Answer (score 2):

Use the event object to get the response ID, and then get the correct response by ID.

```
function myfunction(e) {
  var email, form, formResponse, responseID;

  form = FormApp.openById('Form ID');

  responseID = e.response.getId();

  formResponse = form.getResponse(responseID);

  itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  email = itemResponses[0].getResponse();//Index must be correct

  DriveApp.createFolder(email);
}
```